# How do I reset the scrollback in the terminal via a shell command?

Tags: terminal, bash, command-line

When using Terminal.app, you can clear the screen by using the shell builtin `clear` or by pressing <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Control-L).

However, all this does is push the current screen content back one screen height and reset the cursor/input at the first line. Meaning you can still scroll back and see it.

What you are also able to do, is reset your entire scrollback by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Command-K).

After you've done this, you cannot scroll back at all.

In certain situations (notably, before running `screen` or `vim`), I'd like to reset the scroll back before the command actually executes.

Is there a command (like `clear`) that is implemented in OS X that allows me to do this? Given the existence of `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`, I'm thinking something similar might exist that will allow me to do this.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Terminal supports an extension of the ED (Erase in Display) escape sequence to erase the scroll-back. It is also supported by xterm. The ED command, described in the [VT100 manual](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#ED), accepts these values for the Ps parameter:

```
ESC [ Ps J

Parameter   Parameter Meaning

0           Erase from the active position to the end of the screen
1           Erase from start of the screen to the active position
2           Erase all of the display
```

Terminal ([and xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)) adds:

```
3           Erase the scroll-back (aka “Saved Lines”)
```

Note that this only erases the scroll-back, not the screen. This allows you to erase one or the other, or both by sending two escape sequences.

For example, you can clear the screen and the scroll-back with the following shell command: `clear && printf '\e[3J'`

(The `clear` command looks up the appropriate sequence for clearing the screen for the current terminal, but the “erase scroll-back” escape sequence is custom and must be hard-coded. If you put this in a shell script that you don’t know for certain will only ever be run with Terminal, you should check that `$TERM_PROGRAM` is `Apple_Terminal` before sending it.)

Comment: This is so much faster than osascript!

Comment: This is a much better answer. So, to make this permanent, add to your ~/.bash_profile:

`alias clear="clear && printf '\e[3J'"`

Comment: I put this script in my PATH: `echo $'#!/usr/bin/env bash\n/usr/bin/clear\nprintf \'\\e[3J\'' >clr; chmod +x clr`

Comment: @WalkerHaleIV Why are you creating an executable instead of just printing the escape sequence to stdout?

Comment: $TERM_APPLICATION should be $TERM_PROGRAM

Comment: @pbatey Good catch! After six years! :-) I fixed it.

Comment: i have this in my .bash_profile:
`alias kls="clear && printf '\e[3J'"; alias klear="clear && printf '\e[3J'"`

Comment: You should make `clear && printf '\e[3J'` clearer in your answer for someone that's browsing through quickly

Comment: To advoid duplciation with the current `clean` command, I have used:

`alias clean="clear && printf '\e[3J'"`

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score 34):

⌘K, shortcut to “View > Clear scrollback”.

**UPDATE**: This can be automated with AppleScript by the following command:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down'
```

…which you can of course `alias` to whatever you want, or store in a function in your `~/.profile` login script  :)

As a security though, to be able to use this even in background without risking to issue a keystroke to a wrong front app, I'd advise surrounding it with the following test:

```
if application "Terminal" is frontmost
```

…which gives us the following code:

```
osascript -e 'if application "Terminal" is frontmost then tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down'
```

…which in turns, properly escaped and `alias`ed, ends in:

```
alias clear="osascript -e 'if application \"Terminal\" is frontmost then tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"k\" using command down'"
```

And here is your new `clear`!  :)

Comment: The point here is I'd like to set up something in my shell's environment so that when I run a command (say `vim`), the shell executes the "scrollback reset" before executing vim.

Programmatic, not interactive.

Comment: @JasonSalaz Ok, didn't get that, sorry. Added code for that.

Comment: @JasonSalaz if this answer did solve your problem, please remember to validate it. If it didn't, please get back to us in the comments  :)  Remember, [users from the future](http://xkcd.com/979/) will thank you  ;)

Comment: That comic is about me, you know. I do program in Denver, CO.

(No, not really, it'd be insane if it were, though.)

Comment: This does not work for me. As far as I can tell, it is the equivalent of typing `clear`; that is, it clears the screen, but I can still scroll back. Hitting `Command` `K` works normally.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Are you sure you did `alias clear` in the same session as calling it? Otherwise, if you invoke `clear` later on, you will call the builtin `clear`. You can check that by typing `alias clear`. If it tells you `alias: clear: not found`, then you were calling the builtin  :)

Comment: Pretty sure I didn’t even get that far. I was calling osascript directly. Figured I would get it working before making the alias in my .zshrc.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Well, I confirm copy-pasting and executing the `osascript` line works fine under OS X 10.6.8 and 10.9.2, with the built-in Terminal and bash 4.2. Could you please give more information for reproducing?

Comment: If I type Command-K and then try to scroll up with my trackpad, it does not scroll. If I use the AppleScript, it scrolls past the top line to some blank space. Close, but not identical.

Answer (score 32):

Here's code that works for both macOS' Terminal, and iTerm2. It doesn't need the window to be in the foreground (unlike some AppleScript solutions), either.

```
printf '\e[2J\e[3J\e[H'
```

## How it works

This uses a series of [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Each ANSI escape sequence starts with the "ESC" (escape) character, it's a non-printable ASCII character (meaning it has no visual glyph representation like `1` or `a`). `printf` can print an this character using `\e` (or by its octal value `\033`, or its hex value `\x1B`).

One kind of ANSI escape sequence are the ["Control Sequence Introducer" commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences). They all start with the form `ESC CSI`, where `ESC` is the escape character just mentioned, and `CSI` is the value `[` (or `0x5B` in hex)

I use the `\e[` representation, because it's shorter than `\x1B\x5B`, and easier to read.

As we can see, there are two ANSII escape sequences here, each of which are the "control sequence introducer" form, called with different arguments. Knowing this, we can split up the string into its 3 parts:

1. `\e[2J`

   - The start of an escape sequence (`\e`), containing a control sequence (`[`) with argument `2J`
   - This is an instance of the "ED – Erase in Display" command, which has the form `CSI n J`
   - The `n` value is set to `2` in this case, which invokes the second variant:

     > If *n* is `2`, clear entire screen (and moves cursor to upper left on DOS ANSI.SYS).
2. `\e[3J`

   - The start of an escape sequence (`\e`), containing a control sequence (`[`) with argument `3J`
   - This is an instance of the "ED – Erase in Display" command, which has the form `CSI n J`
   - The `n` value is set to `3` in this case, which invokes the third variant:

     > If *n* is `3`, clear entire screen and delete all lines saved in the scrollback buffer (this feature was added for xterm and is supported by other terminal applications)."
   - Despite the description on Wikipedia, it appears that this isn't actually clearing the screen in iTerm and the default Terminal, only the scrollback buffer was cleared. Hence the need for the `\e[2J` command above.
3. `\e[H`:

   - The start of an escape sequence (`\e`), containing a control sequence (`[`) with argument `H`.
   - This is an instance of the "CUP - Cursor Position" command, which has the form `CSI n ; m H`,

     > Moves the cursor to row *n*, column *m*. The values are 1-based, and default to `1` (top left corner) if omitted. A sequence such as `CSI ;5H` is a synonym for `CSI 1;5H` as well as `CSI 17;H` is the same as `CSI 17H` and `CSI 17;1H`
   - This could have been more explicitly written as `\e[1;1H`

## Fun fact

These control sequences are actually how the built-in `clear` (`/usr/bin/clear`) command works. All it seems to do is product some output, which we can inspect with `xxd`:

```
$ clear | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 481b 5b32 4a                        .[H.[2J
```

We can re-create the same output with `printf '\e[H \e2J'`:

```
$ printf '\e[H \e2J' | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 4820 1b32 4a                        .[H .2J
```

Notice they don't use `\e3J`, hence why `clear` only clears the screen, but not the scrollback.

Comment: Can I ask you where you got it from? +1 from me - it works anyway

Comment: I don't remember, but it's a composition of these:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Looks like it's "`CSI n J`" (where n = 2) + "`CSI n J`" (where n = 3) + "`CSI n ; m H`" (where n, m = 1, 1), which translates to: "ED - Erase in Display" (variant 2), "ED - Erase in Display" (variant 3), "CUP - Cursor Position" (moving to 1, 1)

Comment: A bit shorter: `printf '\e[2J\e[3J\e[;H'`.

Comment: @Isaac Explanation?

Comment: Explanation: A `\e` is (usually) the same a `\033`, and, as the default of `CSI H` is `1;1` there is no need to actually write `\e[1;1H` but `\e[;H` (or even `e[H`) will do the same. It is the same command you wrote but with less characters to type.

Comment: Note that a `printf \\ec` will also reset the whole screen (and scrollback).

Comment: Also note that `printf \\ec` is the only one given so far that works on URxvt, and using `\eP` and `\e\\` as opening and closing markers, respectively, will tell GNU Screen to pass the escape sequences through to the host terminal.

Comment: @ssokolow Hmmm, `printf \\ec` only cleared the screen, but not the scrollback (tested on both iTerm and the default Terminal)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica For my [anon.sh](https://gist.github.com/ssokolow/5a79aef75c45bf9ee0972f961554d2db) "incognito mode for terminal" script, I add `printf '\eP\e[2J\e[3J\e[;H\ec\e\\'` to `clear` to be thorough and then reset GNU Screen's internal scrollback buffer.

Comment: @ssokolow What do `\eP` and `\e\\` do? BTW as someone mentioned above, `\e[;H` can be simplified to `\e[H`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica `\eP` and `\e\ ` are the begin and end markers for telling GNU Screen to pass a bunch of escapes through to the host terminal as-is. As for `\e[;H`, I did see that. I can't remember why I went with the longer version but I probably had a reason from among the half dozen other tabs I also had open at the time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this works on OS X but for Linux the best option seems to be `tput reset`.

Comment: This doesn't work in mac Terminal.app or iTerm2.app but, interestingly, it _does_ work in VSCode's integrated terminal.

Comment: I guess VS Code integrated terminal successfully emulates VT terminal and Terminal.app does something else.